# Repeat a line of code after pressing a key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, repeat

Pretty simple. Is there any way to repeat this code, with the press of a key, indefinitely until i press another key?

The Code:

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    grid.GridScan(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 100);
}
```

Space, in this case, would be the button to start the repeating code. GridScan is a function that needs variables so it won't work with Invokerepeat (I don't think, tell me otherwise if im wrong).

Comment: Repeat how? `for` loop? Every frame? Every three seconds?..

Comment: @AgentFire Like every half second

Comment: then use a coroutine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that with a boolean to execute that in the update. For example:

```
private bool _executeOnUpdate = false;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.anyKey)
    {
        if (!_executeOnUpdate) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
                _executeOnUpdate = true;
        } else {
            _executeOnUpdate = false;
        }
    }
    if (_executeOnUpdate){
        grid.GridScan(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 100);
    }
}
```

That is not tried pseudocode just to give you the idea.
Coroutines are also a good option when you have a specific condition to wait for.

EDIT: Find code with coroutine:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExecuteUntilKeyPressed : MonoBehaviour {
    private IEnumerator myCoroutine;
    private bool _coroutineRunning = false;
    private void Start() {
        myCoroutine = runEveryHalfSec(0.5f);
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
                if (!_coroutineRunning) {
                    _coroutineRunning = true;
                    StartCoroutine(myCoroutine);
                }
                else {
                    StopCoroutine(myCoroutine);
                    _coroutineRunning = false;
                }
            } else {
                StopCoroutine(myCoroutine);
                _coroutineRunning = false;
            }
        }  
    }

    private IEnumerator runEveryHalfSec(float seconds) {
        while (true) {
            Debug.LogError("Running");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        }
    }
}
```

You can attach the script to a gameObject in your scene to see how it works.
Change the `Debug.LogError("Running");` with your `grid.GridScan(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 100);` to then use it in your code.

Comment: Alright that's all working. Is there any way to make this work while i press other buttons? Or does it have to use the "Input.anyKeyDown"?

Comment: sure, you have Input.GetButton that returns true while the button is being pressed https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is: If I press Space and nothing else it will do what I my should until I press space again. But if I press W or anything else, it stops as well. Is there a way to just make it Space to stop it?

Comment: I got from your question "until i press another key". So you want only to start and stop the coroutine only with the space??

Comment: Yeah sorry i'm not the best at explaining things (obviously)

Comment: erase the `if (Input.anyKeyDown) {`and the corresponding else. Then you will have on the inside if that works with the space key